# Grouping dates by factor using R

Tags: r

My data contains three columns.  The first column is a factor that contains approximately 70,000 items of which 4,500 are unique.  The second column are dates and the last column is a count of all the times a factor was performed for a month.

I want to group my data by unique factor.  Is there a simple way to do this in R?  As of now, i've been writing a script in python that identifies the unique factors and using groupby.  I feel like R probably has something that can do this, but i'm just not aware of it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a small example dataset and your expected result.  It is not clear what you meant by `grouping`?  Perhaps, you need to `order`, `sort` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the specifics of your problem or data set. But I'm finding that dplyr is the go to R package for this.

- Here is a good [R
  Studio dplyr webinar](http://pages.rstudio.net/Webinar-Series-Recording-Essential-Tools-for-R.html)
- A great vignette example is the [h_flights vignette](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

I also recommend you look at the resources from DataCamp. They have a good interactive curriculum for R

Here are some dplyr functions that might help

```
group_by() # the factor
select() # variables you want to summarize
summarize() # summarize selected variables
```